# Create dynamic elements by condition using jquery in a structured way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There's a better way to build or create dynamic elements by condition using jquery. Now the code wrote in pure javascript is showed below:

```
if (some_var == some_condition) {
 document.write("<tr>");
 document.write("<td></td>");
 document.write("<td>");
 document.write("<input type='BUTTON' onclick='CheckForm(this.form)' value='Enter'>");
 document.write("<input type='reset' value='Cancel'>");
 document.write("</td>");
 document.write("</tr>");
}
```

I'm struggling with a web page if a lot of code wrote in this way...and I want to put a better  structure and organize this piece of code in understandable block. So I need to deal with the dynamic design, markup and code in a clean approach.

How can I modify the code above using jquery more to turn it more radable and efficient?

There is some resources or articles that can help me using jquery for create different html elements according the needs?

Comment: Is there some reason you need to break it up into multiple statements like this? Also, What's dynamic about it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are 2 ways to create html elements with jQuery, use the one that suits you best. The first option is faster.

## 1

```
var $td = $('<tr><td>Hello world</td></tr>');
```

## 2

```
var $tr = $('<tr/>');
var $td = $('<td/>').text('Hello world');
```

Then you could simply do

```
$tr.append($td);
```

Etc... A simplified example, but you get the idea. Let me know if you want me to elaborate.

Comment: I think its also possible to do `$('<td/>', {text: 'Hello World'})`

Comment: @bullfrog Correct, but I don't use it since it doesn't work in ie7.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `document.createDocumentFragment()`

This way you can use build your html, and then append it as necessary.

```
var data = document.createDocumentFragment();
data.appendChild('<tr><td>hello</td></tr>');
document.getElementById("some-table").appendChild(data);
```

You should not be continuously manipulating the DOM as this is costly.

[Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could keep the HTML in your document and trigger its visibility through CSS, something like:

**HTML**

```
<tr class="onCondition">Rest of the HTML</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.onCondition.hidden { display: none; }
```

**JS**

```
if (someCondition) { $('.onCondition').addClass('hidden'); } // or .hide() and without CSS
```

This approach works logically inversed too, ofcourse.